# FBSDKShareDialogModeNative calls sharerDidCancel on Share click

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a problem with sharing a link via facebook-ios-sdk.

I need to use `FBSDKShareDialogModeNative` for sharing dialog and `FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet` isn't an option for me because I need to set title, description and image for given content which doesn't work in this mode. Every answer I found recommended this mode.

When I use `FBSDKShareDialogModeNative` then the native Facebook app is opened with right content, but after hitting Share button fb app is closed and nothing is shared. Also delegate method `sharerDidCancel` is called.

Only option that works as intended is sharing via browser with mode `FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser`.

**Example code:**

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [FBSDKShareLinkContent new];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];                                                                     // Random
content.contentTitle = @"Test title";                                                                                                // Random
content.contentDescription = @"Test description";                                                                                    // Random
content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg"]; // Random

FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [FBSDKShareDialog new];
dialog.fromViewController = self;
dialog.shareContent = content;
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;

if (![dialog canShow]) {
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser;
}

[dialog show];
```

Does anyone solved this problem? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that I've used wrong `FacebookDisplayName` in plist.

SDK doesn't give you any warning (it fails silently after hitting Done/Share button in fb native) and sharing with wrong display name works in other modes (shareSheet, feedBrowser, etc).

Comment: On a side note, I discovered that this FacebookDisplayName was not necessary at all (I deleted it). In fact, if used to be important but now, if you mistype it you will have that silent shareDidCancel failure. If You delete it, everything should be fine !

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to use this code.

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc]init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];   // Random
content.contentTitle = @"Test title";   // Random
content.contentDescription = @"Test description";   // Random
content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg"];

FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
dialog.fromViewController = self;
dialog.shareContent = content;
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;

if (![dialog canShow]) {
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser;
}

[dialog show];

FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc]init];

content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];                                                                     // Random
content.contentTitle = @"Test title";                                                                                                // Random
content.contentDescription = @"Test description";                                                                                    // Random
content.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gettyimages.pt/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/PT/PT_hero_42_153645159.jpg"]; // 

FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
dialog.fromViewController = self;
dialog.shareContent = content;
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;

if (![dialog canShow]) 
{
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser;
}

[dialog show];
```

Comment: I don't see the difference between my and your code. Only thing that changed is initialization via `alloc] init]` which makes no difference (and same code posted twice which I consider as a mistake). This doesn't share anything to the user's wall.